# jquery scroll to data-image-id

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I am unable to set an id on div containers with various images in them, but want to create a nav with jump links to various sections of the gallery. 
One element that is set on the images that I was hoping to key in on are data- attributes.
Can anyone help me with a function that would let me set a standard jump link

```
<a href="#abc123">A</a>
```

to jump to an image

```
<img src="asdf.jpg" data-image-id="abc123" />
```

My current stab at this was the following, but it returns a:
"Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '{id-in-the-href}' is not a valid selector at HTMLBodyElement.

```
$('#container a[href*="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var jumpTo = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('img[data-image-id="'+jumpTo+'"]).offset().top,
  },
  500,'linear')}
)
```

Comment: Typo error, Just add quote at the end of selector. `$('img[data-image-id="'+jumpTo+'"]')`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function(should be set *id* for attributes) and then just call the function with *id* param

```
    var scrollToBottom = function (jumpTo ) {
        div_height = $("#" + jumpTo ).height();
        div_offset = $("#" + jumpTo ).offset().top;
        window_height = $(window).height();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: div_offset-window_height+div_height
        },'slow');
    };
```

or you can use `$('img[data-image-id="' + jumpTo + '"]')` instead of `$("#"+jumpTo )`

Comment: @AmirBil Thanks for the quick response.
Maybe I misunderstood or just executed this wrong. But I'm getting the same error message (id is not a valid selector). Here is the code I implemented:

Comment: `var scrollToBottom = function (jumpTo ) {   

    div_height = $('img[data-image-id="' + jumpTo + '"]').height();  
    div_offset = $('img[data-image-id="' + jumpTo + '"]').offset().top;  
    window_height = $(window).height();  
        $('html,body').animate({   
            scrollTop: div_offset - window_height + div_height  
        },'slow');  
    };  
    
  $('#container a[href*="#"]').on('click', function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();  
    var jumpTo = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');  
    scrollToBottom(jumpTo);  
  });  
`